# Javascript Simplify condition

Tags: javascript, return, conditional-statements

I would like to ask a help to simplify this condition because there is repetitive

```
if (this.get('fileUrl')) {
      if (this.get('fileContainer.asset_kind') === 'UnsplashAsset') {
        return Asset.create({
          url: this.get('fileUrl'),
          mime_type: this.get('fileContainer.mime_type'),
          isUnsplashObject: true
        });
      } else {
        return Asset.create({
          url: this.get('fileUrl'),
          mime_type: this.get('fileContainer.mime_type'),
          isUnsplashObject: false
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply update `isUnsplashObject` like this and return a single `Asset.create({...})` like:

```
if (this.get('fileUrl')) {
  return Asset.create({
    url: this.get('fileUrl'),
    mime_type: this.get('fileContainer.mime_type'),
    isUnsplashObject: (this.get('fileContainer.asset_kind') === 'UnsplashAsset')
  });
}
```

---

This is kind of same as doing:

```
if (this.get('fileContainer.asset_kind') === 'UnsplashAsset') {
  isUnsplashObject = true
} else {
  isUnsplashObject = false
}
```

Or, using ternary operator like:

```
isUnsplashObject = (this.get('fileContainer.asset_kind') === 'UnsplashAsset') ? true : false;
```

Or, just this as `===` equality check already return a boolean value, so we can simply return that only:

```
isUnsplashObject = (this.get('fileContainer.asset_kind') === 'UnsplashAsset')
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that changes is isUnsplashObject, so put the conditional in there.

```js
if (this.get('fileUrl')) {
    return Asset.create({
        url: this.get('fileUrl'),
        mime_type: this.get('fileContainer.mime_type'),
        isUnsplashObject: this.get('fileContainer.asset_kind') === 'UnsplashAsset'
    });
}
```